# What is this variation of the traveling salesman problem called?

Tags: graph-theory, open-problem

I've encountered a description of a well-known, hard to compute problem. Let us consider $n$ sites that need to be connected in the shortest possible way. If I am only allowed to connect the sites I have a traveling salesman problem. Now, I am allowed to add nodes to the map and connect the sites to those nodes (or even connect two nodes).  What it the name of this problem?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking here.  You said $n$ sites and that they have to be connected in the "shortest" way; are you given pairwise distances for all sites?  When you add a new site, what are the distances from it to all other sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the sites are given as points in the plane, this is the [Steiner tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem).

By the way, if you are trying to do the same thing without introducing additional nodes, as in the initial part of your question, then this is the problem of computing a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), *not* the travelling salesman problem, and can be solved in polynomial time.